# Difference of two non-consecutive rows - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, data-analysis

I have a historical price list and I want to calculate the variation between prices for each currency. My code will update the list by getting the new price and append it to the database. How can I do it?
This is how the elements are on the table :

```
     Date        Hour       Currency     Price      Variation
0   2021-05-01  23:19:21    BAT         1.0700
1   2021-05-01  23:19:21    BTC     47922.1400
2   2021-05-01  23:19:21    DOGE        0.3286
3   2021-05-01  23:19:21    ETH      2451.7400
4   2021-05-01  23:35:50    BAT         1.0600
5   2021-05-01  23:35:50    BTC     47557.2700
6   2021-05-01  23:35:50    DOGE        0.3228
7   2021-05-01  23:35:50    ETH      2438.0300
8   2021-05-01  23:37:20    BAT         1.0500
9   2021-05-01  23:37:20    BTC     47467.0200
10  2021-05-01  23:37:20    DOGE        0.3209
11  2021-05-01  23:37:20    ETH      2435.3000
```

So, as you can see, the currencies are not consecutively placed. For example :

The price variation of BAT :

```
0 -> 4 : (1.0600-1.0700)/1.0700 = -0.93%
4 -> 8 : (1.0500-1.0600)/1.0600 = -0.94%
last_value_index -> recent_value_index : (recent_value-last_value)/last_value
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by `Currency` and then apply `pct_change()` on `Price` column

```
df['Variation'] = 100*df.groupby('Currency').Price.pct_change()
```

**OR Calculating the percentage change manually**

```
df['Variation'] = df.groupby('Currency').Price.transform(lambda x: 100*x.diff()/x)
```

**Output for newly provided df**

```
    Date    Hour    Currency        Price   Variation
0   2021-05-01  23:19:21    BAT     1.0700      NaN
1   2021-05-01  23:19:21    BTC     47922.1400  NaN
2   2021-05-01  23:19:21    DOGE    0.3286      NaN
3   2021-05-01  23:19:21    ETH     2451.7400   NaN
4   2021-05-01  23:35:50    BAT     1.0600  -0.934579
5   2021-05-01  23:35:50    BTC     47557.2700  -0.761381
6   2021-05-01  23:35:50    DOGE    0.3228  -1.765064
7   2021-05-01  23:35:50    ETH     2438.0300   -0.559195
8   2021-05-01  23:37:20    BAT     1.0500  -0.943396
9   2021-05-01  23:37:20    BTC     47467.0200  -0.189771
10  2021-05-01  23:37:20    DOGE    0.3209  -0.588600
11  2021-05-01  23:37:20    ETH     2435.3000   -0.111976
12  2021-05-02  00:04:40    BAT     1.0200  -2.857143
13  2021-05-02  00:04:40    BTC     46883.6300  -1.229043
14  2021-05-02  00:04:40    DOGE    0.3028  -5.640386
15  2021-05-02  00:04:40    ETH     2397.8200   -1.539030
```

#### If we want to fillna with any values like 0.0.

```
df['Variation'] = 100*df.groupby('Currency').Price.pct_change().fillna(0.)
```

Comment: Great, All the best!

Comment: I put more values in my table and there is some variation cell that returns NaN (not the firsts but the lastests). And I calculate that the variation is != 0.

Comment: For the first occurrence of every currency, the variation column will be nan, and the percentage change will be visible from 2nd occurrence of currency.

Comment: I know. In fact, the line 15 has a percentage change equals to NaN but I calculate it manually and the real value is -0.98

Comment: Can you pls add that part of the df to the question, it might be some rounding issue

Comment: I added an answer to the question with my df.

Comment: it's working perfectly, updated the df with solution. It is not giving nans in the middle. Can you please check two things. 1. which version of pandas is being used? 2. Is there any formatting option set on your IDE? BTW - which IDE are you using?Also, please delete the answer in which you have provided new df.

Comment: So, I am using Anaconda/Jupyter, the panda version is 1.1.3 and I am using the chromedriver on Brave. I set no formatting option (at least, not consciously). I relaunch the code and one of three new values has the correct percentual change. The other gives me NaN.

Comment: If possible, please update to the latest version of pandas.

Comment: Updated solution with another option, which might work.